# Security concern for TOTP using keccak?

Tags: one-time-password

I want to implement TOTP in the same manner as RFC 6238 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc6238), but keccak instead of SHA-1.

Keccak follows sponge function with the data rate r and the capacity c.
For lightweight version, the combination of (r,c) may (72,128).
Let's assume that the bitwidth of time is r and the bitwidth of key is c.
And assume that the block Size B = 72.
{Key, Time} is 200b.

I believe Hash(Key, Time) has 3 (ceil(200,72)) times of absorbing rounds and 18(because kecak-f[200]) rounds of squeezing.

Sponge function can take an input bit stream of any length, but as a TOTP, 72b of time is long enough for a specific applications of my interest.

Here is my question.
To reduce the latency, if I skip 3 absorbing rounds and just make the initial State(200b) of the keccak perfumation as r-bit of time and c-bit of key, is there any security degradation? (e.g., Initial state S0 = {Time, Key}).

I believe the initial State is actually same as that of happening in real-world implementation of keccak if the input string is shorter than that of bit-rate r (Only 1 absorbing round). The only difference is that the remaining c bit of the S0 is 0 for the short input and is Key for my question.

Comment: Just checking: why do you care at all about the latency? Keccak is designed to be fast, and the clock skew of all but the most closely synchronized clocks will overwhelm the latency due to computing a full round of keccak on a TOTP-secret-plus-time-length of input. For that matter, the time it takes a human to type the digits in, will overwhelm the latency. Heck, the network latency will overwhelm the computational latency. (Also, is there an important reason to not use SHA1? Its known weakness is entirely irrelevant here.)

Answer (score 2):

The question you're asking is whether using a reduced-round variant of Keccak-200 is secure with a capacity of 128 bits, using a custom initial value.  In the general case, the answer is no, because the capacity should be twice the security strength, and a 64-bit security strength is inadequate for most cases.

However, for TOTP, because the code is very short and the security strength is less than 64 bits anyway, the answer is maybe.  I am not aware of any attacks on this particular construction, but I don't follow the cryptographic literature religiously, and in general my recommendation is not to use custom designs and only use standard, well-trusted constructions that are well vetted by reputable cryptographers.  As a result, I would not use Keccak-200 for general purpose use, I would definitely not use a reduced-round variant of it, and I would absolutely not customize the initial value.  Small and reduced-round variants of algorithms are typically used for analysis and attack, not for practical use.

On my system, OpenSSL offers SHA-3-256 (which is a secure version of Keccak) for 64-byte messages at 85 MiB/s.  (Almost all cryptographic algorithms perform worse on small messages.)  The performance here is more than adequate for TOTP, which typically issues a new code every 30 seconds, must go over an encrypted network connection, and is typically entered by a human, who will always take more time to type the code than it does to compute it.

However, it's better still to use standard methods for TOTP, especially since most users are going to use an application on their phones and it's much better to let everyone use a standard app than install many different custom apps.  While you state you don't wish to use SHA-1, HMAC-SHA-1 is not insecure in this construction.  If you prefer, you can use HMAC-SHA-256 or HMAC-SHA-512 instead, as outlined in the RFC you linked, which, while not supported by Google Authenticator, are supported by a variety of other apps.  There is no substantive reason to prefer Keccak in this construction, and the ability to use robust, well-trusted implementations is compelling, especially since many security problems are due to implementation error, not just poor cryptographic design.